# excel2007 vba: Return to same (Custom UI ribbon) tab after opening another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, custom-controls, ribbon

I was adding ustom UI ribbons with tabs, groups an buttons. This works great. Among the makros I have also adden functions to open another excel files.
My problem is that when I return to original excel workbook, the first tab is always activated, instead of the one which was last used (for ex my custom tab).

**Is there anyone knowing how can I make Excel remembering which tab I was last using?**

For genuine excel tabs this works, only for the custom tab doesn't.

Thank you already for your comments.

OZ

Answer (score 0):

The Application class from the Excel object model provides two events:

- [WindowActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821328(v=office.15).aspx) - is fired when any workbook window is activated.
- [WindowDeactivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822473(v=office.15).aspx) - is fired when any workbook window is deactivated.

Starting from Office 2010 you can use the ActivateTab method of the IRibbonUI interface. See [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691834(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

So, you can implement the required functionality on your own.

Comment: Yes, II thought about this solution, but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution to implement. Is there in Excel2007 no callback function like the getvisibility() for exemple?